# Where can I see predefined methods' code in c#?

Tags: c#, path, .net-assembly

I am looking to see if it is possible to look at the source code of well-known functions

I'm new to programming and early on I am being introduced to methods such as `System.Console.WriteLine();` and was wondering if it is possible to look at the code of this System in some way (such as using object explorer for instance).

I was told that hovering the cursor over and pressing F12 shows the Assembly and metadata: is there a way to look at exactly what `System.Console.WriteLine();` is doing?

Comment: Microsoft published most of NET library source code ad https://referencesource.microsoft.com

Comment: You can find it here: [System.Console](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Since you do have multiple implementations of .NET you do have multiple implementations of the `System.Console.WriteLine()`

- [.NET framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)
- [.NET core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/)
- [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/)

I suppose you are looking for .NET framework but generally, there are multiple implementations.